# How do i plot a pie chart from a pivot table using Python?

Tags: python, excel, pie-chart

I am trying to plot a pie chart based on the data in an excel file.

The Pie Chart in the below picture is the outcome I would like to achieve. The column in the table can be seen in the below picture too.

[Example of Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APTxp.png)

I have tried the below code, but it only crashes my Excel File.

```
import pandas as pd
from xlsxwriter.utility import xl_range

excel_file = 'C:\Project 1 - Scrap qty\Data Summary (2).xlsx'
sheet_name = 'Operation'
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(excel_file, engine='xlsxwriter')

df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Project 1 - Scrap qty\Data Summary.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False)


# Get the max row number for the dataframe.
max_row = len(df)

# Access the Pandas xlsxwriter Excel file.
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets[sheet_name]

# Create a Pie chart.
chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'pie'})

# Add the chart series.
#Operation is the sheet name
chart.add_series({
    'categories': '=Operation!A%s:A%s'%(max_row, max_row),
    'values':     '=Operation!B%s:B%s'%(max_row, max_row),
})

# Insert the chart.
worksheet.insert_chart('F8', chart)

writer.save()
```

Comment: What does the excel file look like? What are the columns?

Comment: Hi, the excel can be seen from the picture attachment above named as "Example of Chart"

Answer (score 0):

try [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/index.html):
you can read your csv using:

```
pd.read_csv('data.csv')
```

It has many parameters. check the doc.
I have made an example to help you:

```
import pandas as pd  
  
# assign data of lists.  
data = {'Operation': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'], 'ALL': [12625, 1795, 3646, 23360, 7171, 1225, 2948,1225]}  
  
# Create DataFrame  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)  
df = df.set_index('Operation')  
# Print the output.  
plot = df.plot.pie( y='ALL', figsize=(5, 5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to do it (with a similar dataset):

```py
import pandas as pd


# Create a Pandas dataframe from some data.
df = pd.DataFrame({'Operation': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'],
                   'Q3': [11108, 1795, 3014, 18450, 6946, 1225, 1575, 1225]})


# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_chart.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
sheet_name = 'Operation'
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name)

# Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets[sheet_name]

# Create a chart object.
chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'pie'})

# Get the dimensions of the dataframe.
(max_row, max_col) = df.shape

# Configure the series of the chart from the dataframe data.
chart.add_series({
    'categories': [sheet_name, 1, 1, max_row, 1],
    'values':     [sheet_name, 1, 2, max_row, 2]})

# Add some other chart formatting.
chart.set_title({'name': '=%s!$C$1' % sheet_name})
chart.set_legend({'position': 'bottom'})
chart.set_style(10)

# Insert the chart into the worksheet.
worksheet.insert_chart('E2', chart)

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

**Output**:

[image]